# Using async await to get data loading

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, async-await, vuejs3

I try use async-await to get data on typescript vue 3, but this function already console when the data is undefined (or before function call working)

```
private async exportDataOrder() {
    await this.getDataExport()                          // function call
    let data = await this.controller.exportOrderData    // result function
    if (data) {
      console.log(data, 'dari vue')
      console.log('waiting')
    }
}
```

Comment: You tagged your question with `typescript`, types would help us helping you. What's the type of `this.controller.exportOrderData`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that `exportOrderData` is an async function, you forgot the `()` to actually call your function.

```
let data = await this.controller.exportOrderData()
```

Comment: Thank u @Alex, that's my mistake :)